# jQuery array object getting value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, xml, parsing

Hey all I have the following code:

```
var items = [];
$(xml).find("Placemark").each(function () {
    var tmp_latLng = $(this).find("coordinates").text();

    tmp_latLng = tmp_latLng.split(",");

    items.push({
        name: $(this).find("name").text(),
        snippet: $(this).find("Snippet").text(),
        description: $(this).find("description").text(),
        lat: tmp_latLng[0],
        lng: tmp_latLng[1],
        distance: $(this).find("distance").text()
    });
});

var markerNodes = items;

if (markerNodes.length > 0) {
     howManyMarkers = markerNodes.length;

     for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
         console.log(markerNodes[i].Snippet);

         var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("Snippet");
         var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("Snippet");
         var description = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("description");
         var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
         var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));

         createOption(name, distance, i);
         createMarker(latlng, name, address);
         bounds.extend(latlng);
     }

     map.fitBounds(bounds);
} else {
     alert('Sorry, there are no stores that close to your location. Try expanding your search radius.');
}
```

The error is on **console.log(markerNodes[i].Snippet);**. The error is *Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function*

Also the **markerNodes[i].getAttribute("Snippet")** has an error of *Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function*

What would I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive. Property snippet is lowercase, use

```
console.log(markerNodes[i].snippet);
```

Comment: and the 2nd undefined issue?

Comment: The same reason exactly.

Comment: what does `markerNodes[i].getAttribute("Snippet")` have to do with the spelling of snippet? What is `getAttribute()`?

Comment: You cannot use `getAttribute`. This function is used to get the attribute value of a HTML DOM object. markerNodes[0] is not an HTML DOM object.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
markerNodes[i].snippet
```

(note the case)

Comment: There is no difference in function between `markerNodes[i].snippet` and `markerNodes[i]["snippet"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Identifiers in Javascript are case sensetive, so it should be `snippet`, not `Snippet`:

```
console.log(markerNodes[i].snippet);
```

The [`getAttribute` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute) are used with elements, not object. Just access the property as a member of the object:

```
var name = markerNodes[i].snippet;
var address = markerNodes[i].snippet;
var description = markerNodes[i].description;
var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].distance);
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markerNodes[i].lat), parseFloat(markerNodes[i].lng));
```

Note: Perhaps you want to get the value for the `name` variable from the `name` property rather than the `snippet` property.